# Using Jackson to serialize a POJO into XML with namespaces and nested elements

Tags: java, xml, soap, jackson

My goal is to create a valid XML request string using a Plain Old Java Object. The problem I am having is that I cannot create multiple wrapping elements, nor can I assign namespaces properly. The code I have right now is:

```
   package test_ground;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

   import java.util.List;

   @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Envelope", namespace = 
   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" )
   public class RateReqModel {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private String Header;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "GetCurrencyRates", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    private List<String> RateDate;

    public RateReqModel(List<String> RateDate){
        this.RateDate = RateDate;
        }
    }
```

**What I am getting with the above script:**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Header/>
  <wstxns1:GetCurrencyRates xmlns:wstxns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <RateDate xmlns="">2021-03-29</RateDate>
  </wstxns1:GetCurrencyRates>
</Envelope>
```

**What I need:**

```
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
    <ns1:Header/>
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:GetCurrencyRates>
            <ns2:RateDate>2021-03-29</ns2:RateDate>
        </ns2:GetCurrencyRates>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

**As you can see, the desired XML structure has 2 namespaces and double wrapping around the RateDate element, which is exactly what I seek.**

Comment: *My goal is to create a valid XML request string using a Plain Old Java Object.* You might have to create more POJOs to wrap other POJOs and get the proper Object to XML structure. It's doable with enough effort. The question is why from a POJO?

Comment: You're right about the effort part. I'm almost there. To answer your question, I am exploring ways of serializing XML files for Rest-Assured usage. The only thing left is that I can't change the localName of the GetCurrencyRates node which is a nested @JacksonXmlRootElement. It has to be "tem:GetcurrencyRates".

Comment: You might find it's easiest to first produce whatever XML Jackson chooses to generate, and then convert it to the specific XML you want using an XSLT transformation.